# Convergence of four integrals

Tags: real-analysis, integration

For which $\alpha$ these integral are convergent ?

> $$\int_0^\infty \frac{t^\alpha}{1+t}dt,\tag{$\bf1$}$$
>   $$\int_0^1 t^\alpha\ln tdt,\tag{$\bf 2$}$$
>   $$\int_0^1\frac{\ln t}{t^\alpha}dt\tag{$\bf 3$}$$
>   $$\int_1^\infty \frac{\ln t}{t^\alpha}dt.\tag{$\bf 4$}$$

**My answers**

**1)** If $\alpha=0$ it doesn't converge. But for the rest I don't know.

**2)** The function is continuous for all $\alpha>0$ therefore it's integrable. For $\alpha=0$ I can integrate by part and it work, but for the rest, How can I do ?

**3)** If $\alpha<0$ we are in the situation of previous therefore it converge, but how can I continue ?

**4)** if I set $t=\frac{1}{s}$, I get
$$-\int_0^1 s^{\alpha-2}\ln sds$$
and thus by previous it converge for $\alpha>2$, but How can I continue ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For (1), split the integral into two terms
$$ \int_0^\infty \frac{t^\alpha}{1+t}dt=\int_0^1 \frac{t^\alpha}{1+t}dt+\int_1^\infty \frac{t^\alpha}{1+t}dt. $$
The first integral converges if $\alpha>-1$ and the second converges if $\alpha<0$ and hence (1) converges if $-1<\alpha<0$.

For (2), note
$$\int t^\alpha\ln tdt=\frac{1}{\alpha+1}t^{\alpha+1}\ln t-\frac1{(\alpha+1)^2}t^{\alpha+1}$$
and hence (2) converges if $\alpha+1>0$ or $\alpha>-1$.

For (3) and (4), use the same argument as in (2).

Comment: For (1) How do you know that the first converge if $\alpha>0$ and the second converge for $\alpha<0$ ?

Comment: Do you know the $p$-integrals $\int_0^1\frac{1}{t^p}dx, \int_1^\infty\frac1{x^p}dx$? The former converges if $p\in(0,1)$ and the latter converges if $p>1$.

Comment: I do, but here is $\int\frac{t^\alpha}{1+t}dt$

Comment: For $\int_0^1\frac{t^\alpha}{t+1}dx$, near $t=0$, $\frac{t^\alpha}{t+1}\approx t^\alpha$.

Comment: To be precise, $t\to 0$, $$\frac{t^\alpha}{t+1}=t^\alpha (1+t)^{-1}=t^\alpha (1+o(1))=t^\alpha+o(t^\alpha)$$